# Error: the if are execute before I click in the button. Only the else is running, but should not be run

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods

I have a Login class and create an instance of it in the Main class, with an instance I'm calling the method start , however in the one term clicking the 'Login' button does not run the  method 'show_entry_fields' correctly. When I execute and click on a Main room I immediately get to the console: 'wrong login'. That is, I do not know why, but I'm execute just the 'else', without having to click the button (or if it is not running). Can someone help or explain what is wrong? Follow the code for both classes (sorry by my english, i don t speak very weel):

```
   from tkinter import *


class Login:

    @staticmethod
    def show_entry_fields(nome, senha):
        if nome == 'admin' and senha == 'admin':
            master.destroy()
        else:
            print('wrong login')

    @staticmethod
    def iniciar():
        master = Tk()
        Label(master, text='Usuário').grid(row=0)
        Label(master, text='Senha').grid(row=1)

        e1 = Entry(master)
        e2 = Entry(master)

        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        Button(master, text='Sair', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
        Button(master, text='Logar', command=Login.show_entry_fields(e1.get(), e2.get())).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
        mainloop()
```

class main:

```
 from FechaLogin import Login

 g = Login()
 g.iniciar()
```